# How to say that you smoke sometimes and only for fun?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request, idioms, expressions

I wonder what do you normally say when you as a smoker would like to indicate that you do not smoke too much and you just do it sometimes and for fun?

> - I'm not a heavy smoker. I......................

The only idiom that I know is "**[joypop](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/joy-popper)**" which reliable dictionaries rarely allude to. So I doubt if it is a common term, or at least it seems to be so colloquial that is used in street language as slang. But what is a common way to say that in English?

Comment: I got rid of my answer as Glorfindel's answer is much more complete to describe the type of smoking you do. However, reading the question again, perhaps the word you might want in this sentence is 'dabble' to indicate you put your 'smoking jacket' on occasionally when the feeling takes you.

Answer (score 4):

[This study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3203138/) refers to them as *casual smokers* or *social smokers*:

> We investigated how adolescents define different smoker types (nonsmoker, smoker, regular smoker, addicted smoker, heavy smoker, experimental smoker, *casual smoker*, and *social smoker*) using multiple indicators of smoking behaviors, including frequency, amount, place, and length of time cigarette smoking, and whether differences exist by smoking experience.

The percentages below indicate what the subjects thinks is a proper definition for casual and social smokers:

> #### Casual smoker
>
> A casual smoker was characterized as an individual who smokes every few months (22.5%), a couple times a month (28.6%), or a couple times a week (27.8%). The amount of smoking for a casual smoker generally ranged from a few cigarettes per month to a few cigarettes per week (66.4%) and tends to smoke at parties (33.5%) or anywhere (36.2%). Over half of the sample (64.8%) characterized casual smokers as having smoked for a few months or for about a year.

> #### Social smoker
>
> Adolescents characterized a social smoker as an individual who smokes a couple times a month or week (62.5%), smokes a few cigarettes per month or week (57.1%), and tends to smoke at parties only (73.3%). Although the length of smoking for a social smoker was widely distributed, the majority of the sample (63.1%) characterized a social smoker as having smoked for a few months or for about a year.